# Truffle console + javascript

Tags: solidity, truffle, javascript, console

I have a question for you guys. I have 2 contracts:

```
contract House { 
  uint public idHouse;
  ...
}

contract ArrayHouse { 
  House[] public arrayHouse;

  function getHouse(uint n) returns(House){
    if (n >= arrayHouse.length) 
      throw;
    return arrayHouse[n];
  }
}
```

I compiled and migrated the contract ArrayHouse to the testrpc reseau. Then, I went to truffle console and tried the following javascript:

1. arrayHouse=ArrayHouse.new(...);
2. arrayHouse.then(function(inst1){meta=inst1;return meta.getHouse(0)}).then(function(inst2){return inst2.idHouse.call();})

I got the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
    at evalmachine.<anonymous>:1:84
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:129:7)
```

I wonder why I cannot access to the an attribute(public idHouse) of an element(House) of my array(arrayHouse). Anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 1):

Only making a guess as I cannot test it at the moment but it seems the way access your contract may be causing the issue. 
Then() should be used on a function to execute after the promise is returned, whereas you are using it on a variable. Try something like this:

`ArrayHouse.new({from: accountAddress});`

`//Or use ArrayHouse.deployed()
ArrayHouse.at(accountAddress).getHouse(0).then(function(inst2){return inst2.idHouse.call();
})`

Answer (score 0):

`getHouse` throws error when `n` is equal to `arrayHouse.length`. You're passing `0` and array is empty so.. you have an exception being thrown.

Other thing is that `idHouse` is just an attribute, so you can't call it as it was a method.